# Grouping text and an image together

Tags: html, css

I *feel* like this should be simple. But I'm not having much luck.

I'm creating a website with a table. The table has headers which contain text to describe the column and an image. For more info users can hover over the image.

But what I'm seeing happen is that the text and the image do not align with each other. Instead the image wraps onto a new line. i.e. For thin columns.

I want to prevent that from happening. So far the only success I've had is by using another table in the table header. Which seems ridiculous.

How can I achieve this?

My html with some attempts.

```
<table class="inline">
    <tr>
      <th>TextA <img class="info" src="/images/info.png" onmouseover="ShowInfo()"/></th>
      <th><table><tr><td>TextB</td> <td><img class="info" src="/images/info.png" onmouseover="ShowInfo()"/></td></tr></table></th>
      <th><span style="display: inline-block;">TextC <img class="info" src="/images/info.png" onmouseover="ShowInfo()"/></span></th>
      <th>TextD <img class="info" src="/images/info.png" onmouseover="ShowInfo()"/></th>
      <th>TextE <img class="info" src="/images/info.png" onmouseover="ShowInfo()"/></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

My style sheet

```
.info {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    float: right;
}

.inline {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    /*display: inline-block;
    table-layout:fixed;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Images and text are both inline elements by default. If they don't get enough space, they will wrap to the next line. Fix that by setting:

```
th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This forces to keep all inline elements (both `display: inline` and `display: inline-block`) on the same line and push the boundaries of the `th` to make it become wider.

Also, you should never use tables to achieve a certain layout. Tables are to contain tabular data. CSS was invented to handle styling.

Comment: Does not work. But I so believed that it should I suspected my image's style. So with nowrap set I removed float: right; from the style. That worked (though the image is misaligned now). Just to be sure I then removed nowrap on the th and it continued to function. Seems the problem was with float: right; on the image.